# C# linq how to filter a list of groups by the objects in the group

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have a list of `MyObject`s

```
class MyObject 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
    bool Approved { get; set;}
}
```

I need to get the *max* `SequenceNumber` where *all* of the objects with that sequence number would have `Approved` as `true`.

Multiple objects can have the same sequence number and some sequence numbers might not be used (its possible there are object with sequence numbers `1, 2, 4` and no objects with `3`)

My idea was to use

```
Objects.GroupBy(f => f.SequenceNUmber).ToList();
```

But I have no idea how to filter the list of groups I get from that.

Is there another way of getting the highest sequence number where all objects are approved or do I just need to somehow filter the list of groups?

Comment: First up, don't skimp on code. `Object { ... }` is not valid C#. Secondly, if you are asking for something, its best to have your code actually working to set up your test data, and show your intended output. This way we can easily copy it, offer a solution, and show you the output... you go away happy (or not).... or someone just answers it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, having

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> Objects = ...
```

we can query it as

```
var result = Objects
  .GroupBy(item => item.SequenceNumber)
  .Where(group => group.All(item => item.Approved))
  .Max(group => group.Key);
```

If there's a possibility, that we *don't have any* `SequenceNumber` where all of the corresponding objects
are `Approved` and we want to return some *default value* (say, `-1`) in this case:

```
var result = source
  .GroupBy(item => item.SequenceNumber)
  .Where(group => group.All(item => item.Approved))
  .Select(group => group.Key)
  .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
  .Max();
```

Comment: Thank you this seems exactly what I wanted. Would it be possible to select the lowest sequence number as a default value if there are no groups where are `objects` are `approved` ?

Comment: @Tomas: `.DefaultIfEmpty(source.Min(item => item.SequenceNumber))` instead of `.DefaultIfEmpty(-1)`